# Jenkins Helm Chart - kubernetes-plugin pulling image from a private gcr

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, docker-registry

I am failing to pull images from a private gcr repo through helm jenkins on a private k8s repo. I am getting:

> rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication.

Is there anyway I can mitigate this error without specifically specifying credentials on pipeline level?

Pulling image from host work and creating a deployment in K8s is pulling successfully, but when pulled within Jenkins it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, had:

```
kubectl -n jenkins patch serviceaccount jenkins -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "gcr-json-key"}]}'
```

... applied on `default` serviceaccount instead of `jenkins`.